# Adding custom properties to default request telemetry

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

How can I add custom properties to the default request telemetry in application insights?  I was able to do that by creating new telemetry client but I would like NOT to do that as it creates duplicate events.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own custom TelemetryInitializer. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#telemetry-initializers.

snipped from the above article:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace MvcWebRole.Telemetry
{
  /*
   * Custom TelemetryInitializer that overrides the default SDK 
   * behavior of treating response codes >= 400 as failed requests
   * 
   */
  public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        // Is this a TrackRequest() ?
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
        int code;
        bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(requestTelemetry.ResponseCode, out code);
        if (!parsed) return;
        if (code >= 400 && code < 500)
        {
            // If we set the Success property, the SDK won't change it:
            requestTelemetry.Success = true;
            // Allow us to filter these requests in the portal:
            requestTelemetry.Context.Properties["Overridden400s"] = "true";
        }
        // else leave the SDK to set the Success property      
    }
  }
}
```

then load that initializer either in the config file or via code, see the doc above for those details.